# How do I calculate the width of each element as a percentage if the elements have margins?

Tags: html, css

In the example below, how do I calculate the width as a percentage so that each of the `li` elements fit on one line? I understand that it's not `25%` since we have to account for the new margins, so what do I set it to?

HTML ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somj9pq2/2/))

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 1.25em;
  width: 25%;
}
li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/29462/582674-kenny.png" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You set the margins in percentages, too.

Comment: @SalmanA How do I figure out the percentage for the margins?

Comment: Use something like `1%`. This would mean the the margin becomes dependent on parent width instead of being a constant (e.g. on 1000px width the margin will be 10px while on 500px the margin will be 5px). But this makes calculation straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your li should be

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
}
```

delete margin-right: 1.25em in li of css

Answer (score 0):

The [clac()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) feature is handy for dealing with this:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 1.25em;
    width: calc(25%-.9375em);
}
```

Because we are only dealing with 3 margins(`3.75em`). We divide that between the four elements, and get `.9375em`

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/somj9pq2/6/)